# Why is the SYS user granted both the DBA role and the SYSDBA privilege?

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle-11g-r2, sysdba, sys

If the `SYSDBA` privilege gives the grantee ultimate authority, then why does the `SYS` user also have the `DBA` role in addition to the `SYSDBA` privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SYSDBA` "priv" is not just another priv, it actually *logs you in as `SYS`*. It doesn't grant you rights in itself... being `SYS` does that.

`DBA` is a *role* that contains a host of system level privileges that control what you can do within the database, regardless of what user you are. So the two things are not overlapping. If you connect `AS SYSDBA` you will actually be `SYS`, and thereby possess the `DBA` role with its privileges (in additional to owning all the dictionary objects).

That being said, it remains to be seen whether the DBA role is even needed by SYS. That depends on whether Oracle's internal code everywhere recognizes SYS as special or whether (in places at least) it relies on the traditional privilege model. I wouldn't want to revoke DBA from SYS and mess up a database to find out!

Comment: So `SYSDBA` is essentially empty and only serves the purpose of allowing you to connect as the `SYS` user, that have the `DBA` role? This doesn't seem right, as users connected as `sysdba` can do beyond what the `DBA` role actually grants.

Comment: Yes that's right. Oracle wanted to allow DBAs to log in as SYS without using the SYS password. So SYSDBA was born as a kind of proxy. Remember the DBA role isn't everything. SYS can also do a ton of stuff simply because it owns all the dictionary objects.

Comment: So from where does `SYS` get the permissions that aren't covered in the `DBA` role if the `sysdba` priv is essentially empty?

Comment: From owning the dictionary. Plus all the system privs (dba_sys_privs) directly granted to it.  Plus all the other roles (dba_role_privs) granted to it besides DBA. Plus any special treatment of SYS within Oracle's code outside of the normal permissions model. DBA isn't really special, it's just a handy package of privs useful to grant to human DBA accounts. I rarely use the DBA role for automation accounts, preferring to grant the specific system and object privs needed instead of relying on a generalized role.